# Discrete Mathematics Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers, recursion

I am studying for the final exam in my Discrete Mathematics class and came upon the following problem on the study guide we were given.

Given the following algorithm:
If $n = 0$, then $f(n) = 0$
else if $n = 1$, then $f(n) = 1$
else $f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)$

For $n\geq 0$, let $c(n)$ be the total number of additions for calculating $f(n)$. (Hint: $c(0) = 0$, $c(1) = 0$, $c(2) = 1$). For $n\geq 2$ express $c(n)$ using $c(n-1)$ and $c(n-2)$.

Also determine if $c(n)\geq 2^{(n-2)/2}$ for $n\geq 2$ and prove your answer.

I believe for the first part we are just to write an equation to find $c(n)$, which I think should be fairly easy, but the second part has me a bit stumped as to how to prove it...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange.  I edited your question and typeset the mathematics.  The formatting is similar to what one would use in LATEX.  Please take a look and see what I did... for future reference.

Comment: I'd point out that counting the total number of additions required to compute the $n$th Fibonacci number is utterly different on whether iteration or recursion is being used.  (And, incidentally, this illustrates why recursion, though sometimes more elegant, is generally a major lose compared to iteration.)  The total number of additions required in the iterative version is merely $c(n) = n-1$.

Comment: And then another advantage is that the answer to the second question is trivially no. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n>2$, in order to calculate $f(n)$ using this recurrence you must first calculate $f(n-1)$, which takes $c(n-1)$ additions, and $f(n-2)$, which takes another $c(n-2)$ additions, and then add the results, which takes one more addition. This will give you the desired recurrence for $c(n)$.

Once you have that, you want to prove or disprove that

$$c(n)\ge 2^{(n-2)/2}\tag{1}$$

for $n\ge 2$. At this point, if not earlier, it would be a good idea to calculate some values of $c(n)$. You should get the following values:

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
n:&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
c(n):&1&2&4&7&12&20&33
\end{array}$$

If you compare that bottom row with the corresponding values of $2^{(n-2)/1}$, you can make a pretty good guess that $(1)$ holds for $n\ge 2$. You can try proving it directly by induction, but it might be easier to take a detour.

Compare that bottom row with $f(n+1)$, and you can discover a formula for the $c(n)$’s in terms of $f(n)$’s, one that’s easily proved by induction on $n$. Then you can use the fact that the Fibonacci sequence is almost a geometric sequence with ratio $\varphi=\frac12(1+\sqrt5)$.